# subversion pre-commit hook error code 255

Tags: linux, bash, svn

I added pre-commit hook script to the repository.

It always gives below error while committing:

```
svn: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 255) with no output.
```

I have already checked that my pre-commit script is having executable permission and its  a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

is added in the beginning of the file.

Even if I write

```
exit 0
```

in the beginning of the file, it is not allowing me to commit and giving the same 255 error.

Now my script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
exit 0
```

and I am again getting the same error while committing.

I just want to know what is error code 255 and how can I make my pre-commit script work properly?

Comment: 255 is a special exit code - it means the exit code was out of range.  verify `/bin/bash` is there? the user the service is running as has executable permissions on it and the script?  Invoke bash as the service user and verify that your simplest of all scripts works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was some format issue. The file was in DOS format. I modified the format from dos to unix and it started working. I installed tool dos2unix and ran below command:

```
dos2unix pre-commit
```

Comment: I spent waaaaay to long trying to find this answer.   Lots of other questions include good things to check, but none covered this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use this command in `Vim` below:

```
:set ff=unix
```